# Data not populating last four weeks from previous year i.e. W50,51,52 - SQL

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, bigdata

I have a code that I have been using to get data for the last few months but when the new year rolled around, I realized that it was not populating any data cause it was not counting the weeks properly.

I wrote the code as week - 4 but it's not giving any data for the last few weeks of December 2023. Can someone help me figure out how to edit the code so it gives me the last few weeks.
I'm assuming it's cause the current week is 1 and 1 - 4 = -3 which doesn't exist.

```
Select id,    
EXTRACT(WEEK FROM transaction_date) as week
    from table1
    where week BETWEEN DATEPART(WEEK, GETDATE())-4 AND DATEPART(WEEK, GETDATE())
```

Comment: What rdbms are you using? `SqlServer` ? `postgresql`? `mysql`? Update your tags to include the correct db being used to point this at your target audience.

Comment: Are you receiving an error message? Do you receive any data at all? Can you provide ddl for the table you are operating on and a handful of sample rows as well as your expected output based on those sample rows?

Comment: Updated. 
And no error messages, just getting week 1 data.
I'm supposed to be getting an id and a customer_id per week for the past 4 weeks based on the criteria I put in the code (removed it for confidentiality purposes) 
the code is working fine. It's just not giving me W52,W51,W50 data as expected

Comment: I think the answers below will address your issue appropriately.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> current week is 1 and 1 - 4 = -3 which doesn't exist.

As this is a data lookup and you have not documented the list of lookup values, the simple answer is to add the missing values to your list. Sure it's a hack, but you have a list of weeks and if -3, -2, -1 and 0 are significant to your logic, then they probably deserve to have an entry in your lookup list.

> If the lookup list has actual calendar dates, and isn't a lookup table at all, then resolve the actual dates from 4 weeks ago, don't use the week number at all!

If you don't feel like adding these entries, this problem is commonly solved by *wrapping* the list, so if your lookup index is less than zero, you can *add* the index value to the *maximum* index in the list.

> let `currentWeek` = `DATEPART(WEEK, GETDATE())`
> let `startWeek` = `currentWeek` - 4
> if `startWeek` < 0 then `startWeek` = 52 - `startWeek`

In SQL that roughly translates to 2 separate criteria:

```
 WHERE
 (   
     week BETWEEN DATEPART(WEEK, GETDATE())-4 AND DATEPART(WEEK, GETDATE())
  OR week BETWEEN 52 + DATEPART(WEEK, GETDATE())-4 AND 52
 )
```

this works due to the OR reference. When current week is 2, the first criteria will match week 1 and 2 (0 and -1 will not exist) but the second criteria will match 52-0 (52) and 52-1 (51). Weeks 53 and 54 are excluded by the hardcoded 52 as the upper boundary in the second BEWTEEN clause.

> I have enclosed these criteria within brackets so that you do not accidentally compose additional criteria over the top of this incorrectly.

Comment: Obviously tweak this to acount for week zero or week 53 if they do exist in your lookup

Comment: WHERE
 (   
     week BETWEEN DATEPART(WEEK, GETDATE())-4 AND DATEPART(WEEK, GETDATE())
  OR week BETWEEN 52 + DATEPART(WEEK, GETDATE())-4 AND 52
 )

This worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Challenges like this are much easier to resolve with the use of a Calendar table.

This becomes a much more straightforward task when you simply use the actual dates, rather than a part of them. Consider:

*assuming TSQL/SQL Server by OPs use of DATEPART*

```
SELECT 
  CAST(DATEADD(WEEK,-4,DATEADD(DAY,1-DATEPART(WEEKDAY,GETDATE()),GETDATE())) AS DATE) AS RangeStart,
  DATEADD(MILLISECOND,-3,CAST(DATEADD(DAY,7,CAST(DATEADD(WEEK,-4,DATEADD(DAY,1-DATEPART(WEEKDAY,GETDATE()),GETDATE())) AS DATE)) AS DATETIME)) AS RangeEnd;
```

| RangeStart | RangeEnd |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-12-03 | 2023-12-09 23:59:59.997 |

```
DECLARE @RangeStart DATETIME = CAST(DATEADD(WEEK,-4,DATEADD(DAY,1-DATEPART(WEEKDAY,GETDATE()),GETDATE())) AS DATE) AS RangeStart,
 @RangeEnd DATETIME = DATEADD(MILLISECOND,-3,CAST(DATEADD(DAY,7,CAST(DATEADD(WEEK,-4,DATEADD(DAY,1-DATEPART(WEEKDAY,GETDATE()),GETDATE())) AS DATE)) AS DATETIME)) AS RangeEnd

SELECT t.id, DATEPART(WEEK,t.transaction_date) AS week
  FROM table1 t
 WHERE t.transaction_date BETWEEN @RangeStart AND @RangeEnd;
```

```
SELECT t.id, DATEPART(WEEK,t.transaction_date) AS week
  FROM table1 t
 WHERE t.transaction_date BETWEEN CAST(DATEADD(WEEK,-4,DATEADD(DAY,1-DATEPART(WEEKDAY,GETDATE()),GETDATE())) AS DATE) 
 AND DATEADD(MILLISECOND,-3,CAST(DATEADD(DAY,7,CAST(DATEADD(WEEK,-4,DATEADD(DAY,1-DATEPART(WEEKDAY,GETDATE()),GETDATE())) AS DATE)) AS DATETIME));
```

Now with less `DECLARE`.

Comment: Oh never used a calendar table before, let me try using it. Thanks!

Comment: ah just realized amazon redshift doesn't have Declare statements

Comment: And the reason for appropriate tagging rears its head.